# Colocar meu e-mail para receber as mensagens de contato

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, blogger

Onde adiciono meu email para receber as mensagens do formulário de contato?

```html
<form name='contact-form'>
<div class='fm_namer'>
<input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='Nome' onblur='this.placeholder = &apos;Name&apos;' onfocus='this.placeholder = &apos;&apos;' placeholder='Nome' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
<input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email' onblur='this.placeholder = &apos;E-mail&apos;' onfocus='this.placeholder = &apos;&apos;' placeholder='E-mail' size='30' type='text' value=''/></div>
<div class='fm_message'>
<textarea class='contact-form-email-message' cols='25' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' onblur='this.placeholder = &apos;Message&apos;' onfocus='this.placeholder = &apos;&apos;' placeholder='Mensagem' rows='7'/>
<input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Enviar'/>
<div class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'>
</div>
<div class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas com `html` a solução seria:

```
<form name='contact-form' action="mailto:seu_email@blabla.com"">
```

Ou utilizando alguma linguagem de programação, se for o caso edite sua questão adicionando a linguagem que estás a usar...

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado!!!

Answer (score -1):

Olá @Miguel Filipe. Você pode utilizar um código PHP para realizar o envio do e-mail. Apenas com HTML isso não é possível. Eu recomendo a biblioteca PHPMailer.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
No GIT deles você encontra vários exemplos.

Hasta la victoria siempre